# Store multidimension array in userdata session codeigniter

Tags: arrays, codeigniter, session

I want to store multi dimension array in codeigniter userdata session. 
when i store a simple array it works fine. but in multi dimension it store nothing. Is there a way to store multi dimension array in session.

My code is:

```
                foreach ($unique_data as $unique_type) {
                $indexes = index_unique_values($product_all_data, 'type', $unique_type['type']);
                foreach ($indexes as $key) {
                    $product_name = $product_all_data[$key]['name'];
                    $product_type = $product_all_data[$key]['type'];
                    $product_status = $product_all_data[$key]['status'];
                    $cost = $product_all_data[$key]['cost'];
                    $price = $product_all_data[$key]['price'];
                    $barcode = $product_all_data[$key]['barcode'];

                    $product_type_all_prod[] = array('name' => $product_name, 'type' => $product_type, 'status' => $product_status, 'cost' => $cost, 'price' => $price, 'barcode' => $barcode, 'cat_name' => '');
                }
            }

            $product_bytype_array = array("product_by_type" => $product_type_all_prod);
            $this->session->set_userdata($product_bytype_array);
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What if you try something like...

```
$this->session->set_userdata(['product_data' =>$product_bytype_array]);
```

You can check that you are actually generating an array in the format you are expecting.

Then check that the Stored result is in the format you are expecting.

```
// What's in the resulting array that we want to store in the session?
var_dump($product_type_all_prod);  

$product_bytype_array = array("product_by_type" => $product_type_all_prod);
$this->session->set_userdata($product_bytype_array);

//What's in the array in the session
var_dump($this->session->userdata('product_by_type'));
```

That should help.

NOTE: I've tested this using CI 3.1.0 with sessions configured as the types File and then as Database.

Comment: Are you using the DB or the File for your sessions. I've only tested it using the sessions file so far...